# Flat closed surface in 3-dimensional loop.

Tags: general-topology

I am not very experienced with Topology, Knot Theory, or anything else this question might entail, but I was wondering if you can draw any loop in 3 dimensions and then draw some flat surface bounded by the loop.  By this I mean to ask if there is any loop in three dimensional space which cannot be the boundary of a flat surface?

Comment: What is a flat surface?

Comment: A flat surface is a surface on which you can do euclidean geometry at every point

Comment: In that case, your surface needs to be homeomorphic to a disk, and as Lee Mosher points out, that's only possible for unknots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The trefoil knot](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Trefoil_knot_left.svg/150px-Trefoil_knot_left.svg.png) is a counterexample. Indeed, if you learn just a little bit of knot theory, you will learn that only the very simplest loops, known as [unknots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknot), can bound flat surfaces.